# How to show date format dd/mm/yyy - dd/mm/yyyy in ngx-boostrap using angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to show date format like this dd/mm/yyy - dd/mm/yyyy but not working.How to change it? and how to get the selected date?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-bsdatepicker-bug-2-f2vrht?file=app/app.component.html

```
<input 
class="form-control" 
placeholder="Two any two days" 
(bsValueChange)="onValueChangeWeek($event)" 
bsDaterangepicker 
[bsConfig]="{ selectWeekDateRange: true, dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY - DD/MM/YYYY' }" 
[(bsValue)]="myWeekValue">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give format in this way,
(code copied from your stackblitz)

```html
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-12 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Two any two days" 
              (bsValueChange)="onValueChangeWeek($event)" 
              bsDaterangepicker 
              [bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat : 'DD/MM/YYYY', dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', showWeekNumbers: false }"
              [(bsValue)]="myWeekValue">
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and in the ts file,

```js
onValueChangeWeek(date){ 
  
    alert(moment(date.slice(",")[0]).format("DD/MM/YYYY")) 
    alert(moment(date.slice(",")[1]).format("DD/MM/YYYY")) 
  
 }
```